# Frechet derivative of nonlinear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

I have the following functional

$F(E(k,t))=\int_0^{k}E(\mu,t)\mu^2d\mu\int_k^{\infty}E(p,t)^{1/2}p^{-3/2} dp $

I would like to compute  $F'(E_0(k,t))$, the Fréchet derivative of $F$ at $E_0(k,t)$.

If I call

$A(E(k,t))=A(k,t)=\int_0^{k}E(\mu,t)\mu^2d\mu $

$B(E(k,t))=B(k,t)=\int_k^{\infty}E(p,t)^{1/2}p^{-3/2}dp $

Using the product rule,I  know

$F'(E_0)=A'(E_0)B(E)+A(E)B'(E_0)$

Now using the method proposed in 
[this answer](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00272156/document).

$A'=\frac{d}{ds}A(E_0+sE_1)|_{s=0}=\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^{k}(E_0+sE_1)\mu^2d\mu |_{s=0}=\int_0^{k}(E_1)\mu^2d\mu$

$B'=\frac{d}{ds}B(E_0+sE_1)|_{s=0}=\int_k^{\infty}(E_0+sE_1)^{1/2}p^{-3/2}dp |_{s=0}=\int_k^{\infty}\frac{E_1}{2}(E_0)^{-1/2}p^{-3/2}dp$

so my result is

$F'(E_0)=B(E)\int_0^{k}(E_1)\mu^2d\mu+A(E)\int_k^{\infty}\frac{E_1}{2}(E_0)^{-1/2}p^{-3/2}dp$

I know that this result is wrong because the good one is

$F'(E_0)=B(E)\int_0^{k}\frac{E_1(\mu,t)}{E_0(\mu,t)}\dot{A}(\mu,t)d\mu-\frac{1}{2}A(k,t)\int_k^{\infty}\frac{E_1(p,t)}{E_0(p,t)}\dot{B}(p,t)dp$

where point denote derivative with respect to $\mu$ for $A(\mu,t)$ and $p$ for $B(p,t)$.

But I do not know where  my mistakes are, maybe is there something liked with the chain rule that I do not consider ?.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your result is fine. The other expression does not make much sense.

Comment: @GV871 What is $k$ and $t$ in your integral? I guess you want the derivative of the function $F$ at the poin $E.$

Comment: Otherwise, you want to define the function of _three_ independent variables $E,$ $k$ and $t$ and the derivative calculation seems wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, $k$ and $t$ are independent variable on which $E$ depends. I think that @daw is right and my results is fine. I have found this [article](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110014260.pdf) that has my same result (page 4, Equation 27)